# Angular/CSS/Javascript creating a popup that can break out of the restriction of the containing div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have an Angular project in which I have some components that run inside of other components, what I'm trying to do is to create a popup component which will have the same size and placement regardless of from where it is triggered.

I got the suggestion to use Bootstrap modals instead, but ran [into this problem trying to implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51455734/angular-6-modal-increasing-the-width-of-the-modal-when-used-as-a-separate-compo) it in Angular. While that problem may be solved, the question of problem of a div breaking out of its containing div still stands.

I've been searching different ways of doing this but haven't found any solutions that I could apply when the exact page position isn't known.

What I want is a div that has the attributes of a div placed with absolute position right in the html, an example of what I mean:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="absolute_div" style="position:absolute; height:80%; width:80%; left:10%; right:10%; margin:0; padding:0;">
    </div>
    <div class="some_content" style="position: relative; height: xx; width: xx">
      <div class="target_div_to_break_out" style="position:absolute; height:80%; width:80%; left:10%; right:10%; margin:0; padding:0;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want the containing div target_div_to_break_out to have the same properties of the absolute_div but am unable to figure out how to achieve that.

In the actual use case there are `<app-popup></app-popup>` tags inside of another dive that i desperately want to break out and be treated as outside the containing div.

Since I'm using Angular for this a solution using Typescript/javascript is more than welcome if it isn't easily achieved in CSS.

Basically I want a containing div to cover 80% of the entire page, regardless of where inside of other divs it is placed.

Comment: Have you considered using `fixed` positioning on the `target_div_to_break_out`?

Comment: @user184994 ...I'm so bad at front-end that it's astonishing, yep that solved it, post it as an aswer an I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `absolute` positioning (which will position it relative to it's first positioned ancestor, i.e. `.some-content`), you should use `fixed` positioning, which will position it relative to the entire viewport.

More info on CSS positions can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)